# Consul for authentication in microservices architecture

Tags: spring, microservices, consul, spring-cloud-consul

can anyone please help me understand how does consul authenticate micro-services in a micro-services architecture and can we replace the micro-service authentication  (which is using oauth2) with consul ?

Comment: What do you mean by consul authenticate? are you talking about  https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-consul or

Comment: when i watched the video that the company did to present consul he said that consul can manage how is one microservice is allowed or not to contact another and how can microservice A be sure that it is B who is trying to call him not some other malicious microservice .. i wanted to know if anyone has tried to use consul in that way coz i dont seem to find any documentation on the net but that single video

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for the [Service segmentation](https://www.consul.io/segmentation.html) use case of consul

Comment: yes ! i've been diving into the documentation and kind od understood the hows and whys .. just one more how .. how can i integrate that segmentation service with my spring boot based micro-services architecture

Comment: For consul we had gone for a docker based integration.

Comment: https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/getting-started/connect this should be a good start

Comment: yeah i've seen that , but still the vision is not so clear that's why i posted the question . i want to see how can we replace the athentication micro-service with consul connect.

Comment: I guess you are talking about the user authentication and authorization. There are two separate concerns 1. Authentication  and authorization of service end points exposed to the end user. 2. Another one is authentication and authorization of inter service call.

Comment: Connect is a solution for the second one i.e inter service calls. You need to check whether this relevant for you.

Comment: For the first one, which is the common application concern. You may use your own mechanisms  usually OAuth, Ldap.